# Ionic can't find project files ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I've started my app project using standard file organization. Then I've switched to a more elaborate folder structure. 
When I run my app on Chrome through (ionic serve) everything works flawlessly but when I deploy my app to my phone through Cordova(ionic run android) it can't find the custom files I've created.

It seems like there is some sort of permission missing. Any ideas of what might be wrong?

update: the app project also exists under /platforms/android/assets/.
In that folder the "www/components/..." files exist.

**path: www / templates / client.html
    -----> THIS WORKS**

```
.state('app.client', {
    url: '/client',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/client.html',
            controller: 'ClientCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

**path: www / components / client / views / client.html
   -----> THIS DOESNT WORK**

```
.state('app.client', {
        url: '/client',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'components/client/views/client.html',
                controller: 'ClientCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
```

index.html
Using chrome's debugging I noticed that the client JS files are not accessible. Hence, it could be some problem with gulp and how it copies the files into the APK file...

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>


<script src="components/client/client-controller.js"></script>        
<script src="components/client/client-service.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show your folder structure?

Comment: Is component folder is in your WWW folder?

Comment: www > components > client > views.

Also, the controller and the service for Client entity is at www > components > client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOUND THE PROBLEM!!

The issue was not related to folder permissions but with cached build files.

First time I've created the folder I did it with capital letters. "Components/Client/View"

After I've renamed the files both in the code and physical files the changes didn't work because the process of ionic build keeps cache of folder structure.

Deleting the content of /android/build/ folder solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Views in an Ionic App are often referred to as templates because Angular controllers refer to them as such. Because of this, views are often stored in a /templates folder where each view is in a separate .html file. So, my suggestion would be to keep your components folder inside the templates folder such that the route for your templateUrl would be: templates/components/client/views/client.html.
Also, the controller and service filepath must be defined in the index.html. Hope it suffices your needs.

Comment: unfortunately it would demand me to change where I store my js files as well. If no better approach presents... I will have to do that.